# Different link if user logged in or not

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I need your help, it might be simple for someone but hard for me .
I have website on wordpress with a theme.
On my home page I have a button "Sale" 
I would like to add a link to the button  :
-If people are logged in --> the link is https://www......./my-account_vendre
-If they are not logged in -->the link redirect to https://www......./register
Can someone can help me with the code (PHP I guess)can I can add to me function.php
Thanks a lot

Comment: you can use the core function `is_user_logged_in()` - which Checks if the current visitor is a logged in user. it returns true/false, and create the link from there.

Comment: this would be in the theme though - not in functions

Answer (score -1):

You can use :

```
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
     echo '<a href="">With login Redirection</a>'
 }else{
     echo '<a href="">without login Redirection</a>';
 }
```

Or you are trying to add a button with page-editor, You can create the shortcode like:

```
function mjt_btn_resirection(){
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
     $link = '<a href="">With login Redirection</a>';

 }else{
    $link = '<a href="">without login Redirection</a>';
 }
    return $link ; 
}
add_shortcode('btn_resirection','mjt_btn_resirection');
```

and add button with shortcode:

```
[btn_resirection ]
```